# Multiple loops in python

Tags: python, loops, logic

I have code that runs through several strings and when it finds them it executes several commands, however when I run it it works fine for the first string, and then it acknowledges it should start for the second string but it then it doesn't execute the rest and I don't know why.

Code:

```
import os
import json
import shutil
import re


d='.'
folders = list(filter (lambda x: os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d, x)), os.listdir(d)))
print("Folders found: ")
print(folders)
print("\n")


def processModelFolder(inFolder):

#Creating the file names nessecary and storing them as variables
    fileName = os.path.join(d, inFolder, inFolder + ".mdl")
    fileNameTwo = os.path.join(d, inFolder, inFolder + ".vg2.json")
    fileNameThree = os.path.join(d, inFolder, inFolder + "APPENDED.vg2.json")
#copying the json file so the new copy can be appended
    shutil.copyfile(fileNameTwo, fileNameThree)
#opening files
    mdl = open(fileName , "r")
    jsonCopy = open(fileNameThree , "r+")
#assigning IDs and properties to search for in the mdl file
    IDs = ["6ff0010c-00fe-485b-b695-4ddd6aca4dcd" , "ab7fbf37-17bb-4e60-a543-634571a0fd73"]
    Properties = ["IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_ANIMATION_TIME[0]" , "IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATIONS_FOR_ITERATION"]
#nested loops to search first for each ID, and then an ID is found to search that one for each property
    for i in IDs:
        print("Searching new ID: " + i + "\n")
        searchIDs(mdl, jsonCopy, IDs, Properties, i)




def searchIDs(mdl, jsonCopy, IDs, Properties, i):
    lineNum = 0
    for line in mdl:
        lineNum += 1
        if i in line:
            ID = i
            print("Line number is: ")
            print(lineNum)
            print("ID is: " + ID)
            print("Line is: " + line)
            searchProp(mdl, jsonCopy, IDs, Properties, lineNum, ID)



def searchProp(mdl, jsonCopy, IDs, Properties, lineNum, ID):
    for y in Properties:
        mdl.seek(lineNum)
        for line in mdl:
            if line.find("[/IDO") == -1:
                if y in line:
                    #code here for json file work
                    print("ID is: " + ID + "\nProperty is: " + y + "\nThe full line is: " + line)
            else:
                print("The last line read is:" + line)
                break








for modelFolder in folders:
    processModelFolder(modelFolder)
```

Here is the output I get:

```
Folders found: 
['2-stufiges Stirnradgetriebe_20190221-091307']


Searching new ID: 6ff0010c-00fe-485b-b695-4ddd6aca4dcd

Line number is: 
4
ID is: 6ff0010c-00fe-485b-b695-4ddd6aca4dcd
Line is: IDCO_IDENTIFICATION = "6ff0010c-00fe-485b-b695-4ddd6aca4dcd"

ID is: 6ff0010c-00fe-485b-b695-4ddd6aca4dcd
Property is: IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_ANIMATION_TIME[0]
The full line is: IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_ANIMATION_TIME[0] = 2.0

The last line read is:[/IDO_SYSTEM_LOADCASE] [0]

ID is: 6ff0010c-00fe-485b-b695-4ddd6aca4dcd
Property is: IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATIONS_FOR_ITERATION
The full line is: IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATIONS_FOR_ITERATION[0][0] = 1

ID is: 6ff0010c-00fe-485b-b695-4ddd6aca4dcd
Property is: IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATIONS_FOR_ITERATION
The full line is: IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATIONS_FOR_ITERATION[0][1] = 115

ID is: 6ff0010c-00fe-485b-b695-4ddd6aca4dcd
Property is: IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATIONS_FOR_ITERATION
The full line is: IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATIONS_FOR_ITERATION[0][2] = 14

The last line read is:[/IDO_SYSTEM_LOADCASE] [0]

Searching new ID: ab7fbf37-17bb-4e60-a543-634571a0fd73
```

As you can see at the very end it sees the new string to look for, but it doesn't work like it does on the first string. I double checked the file it is searching and it definitely should find additional matching strings.

Edit**
Here is the text from the text file that it searches:

```
[/] [0]
[IDCO_CALCOBJECT_DATA]
IDCO_IDENTIFICATION = "6ff0010c-00fe-485b-b695-4ddd6aca4dcd"
IDCO_DESIGNATION = "Stirnradgetriebe"
[IDSCO_CALCULATION]
IDSCO_NBITERATIONSTEPS = 200
IDSCO_DELTA_X_VECTOR_LIMIT = 0.00001
IDSCO_Y_VECTOR_LIMIT = 0.00001
IDSCO_CALCULATION_SCOPE = CALCULATE_ALL_WITHOUT_CONTACTPRESSURE_FOR_SHAFTSYSTEMS
IDSCO_IS_LOAD_CASE_REPRESENTING_SYSTEM_CALCOBJECT = IFALSE
IDSCO_LIFE_THEORY_FOR_SYSTEMS = LB_BEARING_ANALYSIS_NOMINAL_LIFE
IDSCO_LIFE_THEORY_FOR_ALL_BEARINGS_IN_SYSTEMS = LB_BEARING_ANALYSIS_NOMINAL_LIFE
IDSCO_OPERATION_PORTION_DEFINITION_FLAG = LB_OPERATING_PORTION
IDSCO_POSITION_DEPENDENCY_OF_RATINGLIFE = LB_POSITION_DEPENDENT_RATINGLIFE
IDSCO_CALCULATE_ROLLING_ELEMENT_RATINGLIFE = LB_DONT_CALCULATE
IDSCO_CALCULATE_CATALOGLIFE_FOR_TAPERED_ROLLER_BEARINGS = LB_CALCALATED_FROM_FROM_BALANCE_OF_THE_ELASTIC_SYSTEM
IDSCO_INPUT_OF_DEAD_WEIGHT = LB_LOAD_CASE_DEPENDENT_VALUES
IDSCO_CONSIDERATION_OF_SHEAR_AND_BENDING_FLAG = LB_CONSIDER_SHEAR_AND_BENDING
IDSCO_INFLUENCE_FACTORS_CALCULATION = LB_INFLUENCE_FACTORS_CLASSIC
IDSCO_KINEMATIC_MODEL = LB_NOT_LINEARISED_KINEMATIC
IDSCO_MASS_FORCES_OF_ROLLING_ELEMENTS = LB_DO_NOT_CONSIDER
IDSCO_LIFE_ACCORDING_DIN_281_SUPPLEMENT_1 = LB_NO_LIFE_ACCORDING_DIN_281_SUPPLEMENT_1
IDSS_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_SHOULD_BE_PERFORMED = LB_NO
IDSCO_CONSIDER_NONPOINT_LOADDISTRIBUTION_IN_TOOTH_CONTACTS = LB_NO
IDSCO_CALCULATE_FRICTIONAL_TORQUE = LB_DONT_CALCULATE
IDSCO_CHECK_RANGE_FOR_FRICTION_CALCULATION = LB_DONT_CHECK_RANGE
IDG_CALCULATE_CONSUMPTION = LB_DONT_CALCULATE
IDG_CALCULATE_TOOTH_CONTACT_DATA = LB_CALCULATE
IDSCO_LUBRICATION_AND_CONTAMINATION = LB_CONSIDER
ID_GEAR_SET_INTERN_MODELING = ID_GEAR_SET_ROTATION_MODEL_WITH_USE_OF_EXTERNAL_LOADS
ID_TOOTH_CONTACT_CALCULATION_COMPLETE_SYSTEM = IFALSE
IDSCO_DAMAGE_FACTOR_CALCULATION = LB_NO
IDSCO_LINE_CONTACT_MODEL_FOR_FRICTION_CALCULATION = LB_HERTZ_FOR_FRICTION_CALCULATION
[IDSCO_LIFE_OUTPUT]
IDSCO_LIFETIME_UNIT = LF_HOURS
IDSCO_NECESSARY_LIFETIME_COMPARISON_FLAG = LB_CALCULATE_NECESSARY_LOAD_RATING
IDSCO_NOMINAL_LIFETIME = 0.1
IDSCO_NOMINAL_S0 = 1.0
[IDSCO_LUBRICANT]
IDSCO_VISCOSITY_CALCULATION_FLAG = LB_CALCULATE_VISCOSITY_GLOBAL
IDSCO_ETA_C_CALCULATION_FLAG = LB_INPUT_ETAC
IDSCO_LUBRICANT_DEFINITION_FLAG = LB_DEFINITION_BY_INPUT
IDSCO_VISCOSITY_DEFINITION_FLAG = LB_DEFINITION_BY_CLASS
IDSCO_WARNING_FLAG_FOR_GREASE = ITRUE
IDSCO_OILTEMP[0] = 70.0
IDSCO_NY[0] = 55.2
IDSCO_NY_40 = 240.0
IDSCO_NY_100 = 1.0
IDSCO_OIL_DENSITY[0] = 890.0
IDSCO_ADDITIVES = LB_NO_ADDITIVES
IDSCO_KAPPA_CALCULATION_FLAG = LB_ACCORDING_ISO_281
IDSCO_ETA_C[0] = 0.70
IDSCO_FILTRATION = LB_FILTERED_OIL
IDSCO_LUBRICANT_TYPE = LB_OIL_LUBRICATION
IDSCO_CLEANLINESS_CODE_RECIRCULATING_OIL = LB_ISO17_14_DP25
IDSCO_CLEANLINESS_CODE_OIL_BATH = LB_ISO17_14
IDSCO_CLEANLINESS_CODE_GREASE = LB_NORMAL_CLEANLINESS_GREASE
IDSCO_INITIAL_GREASING = LB_YES
IDSCO_DESIGNATION_OF_GREASE = LB_GA01
IDSCO_INFLUENCE_OF_AMBIENT = LB_AVERAGE_AMBIENT_INFLUENCE
IDSCO_CALCULATE_GREASE_SERVICE_LIFE = LB_NO
IDSCO_SPECIFICATION_OF_OIL_LEVEL = LB_DESCRIPTION
IDSCO_OIL_LEVEL_RELATIVE_TO_DW = 50.00
IDSCO_DESCRIPTION_OF_OIL_LEVEL = LB_OIL_MIST_LUBRICATION
[IDSCO_MBS_CALCULATION_SUMMARY]
IDSCO_MBS_CALCULATION_LEVEL[0][0] = "InitialValueCalculation"
IDSCO_MBS_CALCULATION_LEVEL[0][1] = "NonLinearElasticPreCalculation"
IDSCO_MBS_CALCULATION_LEVEL[0][2] = "FinalCalculation"
IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_SOLUTION_VARIANTS[0][0] = 1
IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_SOLUTION_VARIANTS[0][1] = 1
IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_SOLUTION_VARIANTS[0][2] = 1
IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_JACOBIAN_CALCULATIONS[0][0] = 1
IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_JACOBIAN_CALCULATIONS[0][1] = 12
IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_JACOBIAN_CALCULATIONS[0][2] = 2
IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATIONS_FOR_JACOBIAN[0][0] = 57
IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATIONS_FOR_JACOBIAN[0][1] = 673
IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATIONS_FOR_JACOBIAN[0][2] = 113
IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATIONS_FOR_ITERATION[0][0] = 1
IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATIONS_FOR_ITERATION[0][1] = 115
IDSCO_MBS_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATIONS_FOR_ITERATION[0][2] = 14
IDSCO_MBS_TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATIONS[0][0] = 58
IDSCO_MBS_TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATIONS[0][1] = 788
IDSCO_MBS_TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATIONS[0][2] = 127
IDSCO_MBS_TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_EVALUATIONS_LOADCASE[0] = 973
IDSCO_MBS_SYSTEM_SIZE[0][0] = 56
IDSCO_MBS_SYSTEM_SIZE[0][1] = 56
IDSCO_MBS_SYSTEM_SIZE[0][2] = 56
IDSCO_MBS_JACOBIAN_STEP_SIZE = 0.0000010
IDSCO_MBS_JACOBIAN_STEP_SIZE_MINIMUM = 0.000001000
[IDG_LIFE]
IDG_IA = 0.001
IDG_RDYN = 0.001
IDG_FLAG_FOR_NECESSARY_REVOLUTION_REFERENCE = LB_BEARING_AS_REFERENCE
IDG_TOTAL_OPERATING_TIME_IN_SECONDS = 0.0
IDG_TOTAL_DISTANCE = 0.000
[IDG_OPERATING_DATA]
IDG_EFFICIENCY[0] = 100.0
IDG_BEARING_IDENTIFICATION_MINIMUM_LH = "e1f0ec0b-9ea7-4009-a3ff-77bf9bad5ae8"
IDG_BEARING_NAME_MINIMUM_LH = "SL182220 (#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)"
IDG_MINIMUM_LH = 19436916
IDG_BEARING_IDENTIFICATION_MINIMUM_S0 = "e1f0ec0b-9ea7-4009-a3ff-77bf9bad5ae8"
IDG_BEARING_NAME_MINIMUM_S0 = "SL182220 (#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)"
IDG_MINIMUM_S0 = 120.982
IDCO_BEARING_MINIMUM_S0_W = "e1f0ec0b-9ea7-4009-a3ff-77bf9bad5ae8"
[IDCO_VISUALIZATION]
IDCO_VISUALIZATION_STATUS = LB_SOLID_BODY
IDCO_VISUALIZE_LABEL = IFALSE
IDCO_VERTICAL_LABEL_POSITION = 30
IDCO_HORIZONTAL_LABEL_POSITION = 30
IDCO_DEPTH_LABEL_POSITION = 0
[IDSCO_VISUALIZATION]
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_LOAD_DISTRIBUTION = 0.010
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_CONTACT_PRESSURE = 0.010
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_DISPLACEMENT = 100.000
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_TILTING = 100.000
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_SECTION_FORCE = 0.010
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_SECTION_MOMENT = 0.010
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_STRESS = 0.010
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_TORSION = 100.000
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_FE_STRUCTUR_ELASTIC = 1.0
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_FE_STRUCTUR_RIGID = 1.0
IDSCO_CONTOUR_PLOT_RAMP_FE_MIN = 0.00000
IDSCO_CONTOUR_PLOT_RAMP_FE_MAX = 1.00000
IDSCO_CONTOUR_PLOT_SHOW_FE = IFALSE
IDSCO_CONTOUR_PLOT_FE_DISPLACEMENT = LB_AUTOMATIC_INPUT
IDSCO_GRAVITY_DIAMETER = 20.000
IDSCO_GRAVITY_LOCATION_X = 0.000
IDSCO_GRAVITY_LOCATION_Y = 0.000
IDSCO_GRAVITY_LOCATION_Z = 0.000
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_ALGORITHM = LB_SCALE_FACTOR_FROM_MODEL_DIMENSIONS
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_LOADS_MM_PER_UNIT = 0.010
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_MOMENTS_MM_PER_UNIT = 0.010
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_DISTRIBUTED_LOADS_MM_PER_UNIT = 0.010
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_DISTRIBUTED_MOMENTS_MM_PER_UNIT = 0.010
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_ACCELERATION_MM_PER_UNIT = 100.000
IDSCO_USER_VIEW_NUMBER_VIEWS = 0
IDSCO_USER_VIEW_VIEW_NAME[0] = "-"
IDSCO_USER_VIEW_CAMERA_TYPE[0] = 0
IDSCO_USER_VIEW_POSITION_X[0] = 0.000
IDSCO_USER_VIEW_POSITION_Y[0] = 0.000
IDSCO_USER_VIEW_POSITION_Z[0] = 0.000
IDSCO_USER_VIEW_ROTATION_Q0[0] = 0.000
IDSCO_USER_VIEW_ROTATION_Q1[0] = 0.000
IDSCO_USER_VIEW_ROTATION_Q2[0] = 0.000
IDSCO_USER_VIEW_ROTATION_Q3[0] = 0.000
IDSCO_USER_VIEW_FAR_DISTANCE[0] = 0.000
IDSCO_USER_VIEW_NEAR_DISTANCE[0] = 0.000
IDSCO_USER_VIEW_FOCAL_DISTANCE[0] = 0.000
IDSCO_USER_VIEW_HEIGHT_ANGLE[0] = 0.000
[IDCO_OPERATING_DATA]
IDCO_IS_3D_TOOTH_CONTACT = IFALSE
[IDG_SYNCHRONIZERS_DATA]
IDG_SYNCHRONIZERS_METHOD_DIMENSIONING_OR_DESIGNING = LB_DIMENSIONING
IDG_SYNCHRONIZERS_GEAR_WITH_SYNCHRONIZATION_SYSTEMS = IFALSE
[IDSS_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_DATA]
IDSS_BASIS_MAX_FREQUENCY = 10471.975511966
IDSS_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_CONSIDER_STIFFENING_DUE_TO_AXIAL_LOAD = LB_YES
IDSS_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_FILTEROUT_0_FREQUENCIES = LB_YES
IDSS_NATURAL_FREQUENCIES_SHOULD_BE_CALCULATED = LB_YES
IDSS_STATUS_OF_NATURAL_FREQUENCIES_CALCULATION[0] = IFALSE
IDSS_CRITICAL_SPEEDS_SHOULD_BE_CALCULATED = LB_NO
IDSS_STATUS_OF_CRITICAL_SPEEDS_CALCULATION[0] = IFALSE
IDSS_TRANSIENT_RESPONSE_SHOULD_BE_CALCULATED = LB_NO
IDSS_STATUS_OF_TRANSIENT_RESPONSE_CALCULATION[0] = IFALSE
IDSS_UNBALANCE_RESPONSE_SHOULD_BE_CALCULATED = LB_NO
IDSS_UNBALANCE_RESPONSE_LOWER_ROTATING_SPEED = 0.000000000000000000
IDSS_UNBALANCE_RESPONSE_UPPER_ROTATING_SPEED = 100000.000000000
IDSS_UNBALANCE_RESPONSE_NUMBER_OF_CALCULATION_STEPS = 100
IDSS_STATUS_OF_UNBALANCE_RESPONSE_CALCULATION[0] = IFALSE
IDSS_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_CALL_DYNLIB = LB_YES
IDSS_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_SAVE_DYNLIB_MODEL_TO_INTERMEDIATE_FILE = LB_NO
IDSS_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_PATH_TO_DYNLIB_INTERMEDIATE_FILE = "DynLibModel.xml"
[IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION]
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_MODESHAPES_RELATIVE_SCALE_FACTOR[0] = 2.0
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_MODESHAPES_RELATIVE_SCALE_FACTOR_TORSION_LINE[0] = 0.3
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_RELATIVE_SCALE_FACTOR[0] = 5.0
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_SCALE_FACTOR_DISPLACEMENT[0] = 1000.0
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_SCALE_FACTOR_INCLINATION[0] = 1.0
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_SCALE_FACTOR_FORCE[0] = 1.0
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_SCALE_FACTOR_MOMENT[0] = 1.0
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_SCALE_FACTOR_SPEED[0] = 1.0
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_SCALE_FACTOR_ACCELERATION[0] = 1.0
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_ANIMATION_TIME[0] = 2.0
[IDCO_IMPORT_LOAD_DATA]
IDCO_FILE_NAME = ""
IDCO_FIRST_DATA_LINE = 1

[/IDO_SYSTEM_LOADCASE] [0]
[IDCO_CALCOBJECT_DATA]
IDCO_IDENTIFICATION = "1dd94d1a-e52d-40b3-a82b-6db02a8fbbab"
IDCO_DESIGNATION = "Lastfall 1"
[IDSLC_SYSTEM_LOADCASE_DATA]
IDSLC_TIME_PORTION = 100.000
IDSLC_DISTANCE_PORTION = 100.000
IDSLC_OPERATING_TIME_IN_HOURS = 1.000
IDSLC_OPERATING_TIME_IN_SECONDS = 3600.000
IDSLC_OPERATING_REVOLUTIONS = 1
IDSLC_OPERATING_DISTANCE = 1.000
IDSLC_ACCELERATION = 9.81000
IDSLC_EPSILON_X = 0.000000000000000000
IDSLC_EPSILON_Y = 0.000000000000000000
IDSLC_EPSILON_Z = 0.000000000000000000
IDSLC_CALCULATION_WITH_OWN_WEIGHT = CO_CALCULATION_WITHOUT_OWN_WEIGHT
IDSLC_CALCULATION_WITH_TEMPERATURE = CO_CALCULATION_WITH_TEMPERATURE
IDSLC_FLAG_FOR_LOADCASE_CALCULATION = LB_CALCULATE_LOADCASE
IDSLC_STATUS_OF_LOADCASE_CALCULATION = ITRUE

[/IDO_SHAFT_SYSTEM] [0]
[IDCO_CALCOBJECT_DATA]
IDCO_IDENTIFICATION = "ab7fbf37-17bb-4e60-a543-634571a0fd73"
IDCO_DESIGNATION = "#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"
[IDSCO_SYSTEMDATA]
IDSCO_SEGMENT_GEOMETRY_REFERENCE_FLAG = LB_IDSCO_SEGMENT_GEOMETRY_REFERENCE_END
[IDSCO_CALCULATION]
IDSCO_NBITERATIONSTEPS = 200
IDSCO_DELTA_X_VECTOR_LIMIT = 0.00001
IDSCO_Y_VECTOR_LIMIT = 0.00001
IDSCO_CALCULATION_SCOPE = CALCULATE_ALL_WITHOUT_CONTACTPRESSURE
IDSCO_IS_LOAD_CASE_REPRESENTING_SYSTEM_CALCOBJECT = IFALSE
IDSCO_LIFE_THEORY_FOR_SYSTEMS = LB_BEARING_ANALYSIS_NOMINAL_LIFE
IDSCO_LIFE_THEORY_FOR_ALL_BEARINGS_IN_SYSTEMS = LB_BEARING_ANALYSIS_NOMINAL_LIFE
IDSCO_ORIGIN_OF_LIFE_THEORY_FLAG = LB_FROM_SYSTEM
IDSCO_TRANSLATORY_DEFORMATION_LIMIT = 2.463
IDSCO_ROTATORY_DEFORMATION_LIMIT = 2.000
IDSCO_POSITION_DEPENDENCY_OF_RATINGLIFE = LB_POSITION_DEPENDENT_RATINGLIFE
IDSCO_CALCULATE_ROLLING_ELEMENT_RATINGLIFE = LB_DONT_CALCULATE
IDSCO_HAS_LOADS_TO_DISCRETIZE = IFALSE
IDSCO_HAS_SHAFTS_WITH_FEA_DATA = IFALSE
IDSCO_LOAD_CASE_MUST_BE_DISCRETIZED[0] = IFALSE
IDSCO_IDENTIFICATION_OF_LOAD_CASE_REPRESENTING_SYSTEM_CALCOBJECT[0] = ""
IDSCO_KINEMATIC_MODEL = LB_NOT_LINEARISED_KINEMATIC
IDSCO_LIFE_ACCORDING_DIN_281_SUPPLEMENT_1 = LB_NO_LIFE_ACCORDING_DIN_281_SUPPLEMENT_1
IDSS_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_SHOULD_BE_PERFORMED = LB_NO
IDSCO_MASS_FORCES_OF_ROLLING_ELEMENTS = LB_DO_NOT_CONSIDER
IDSCO_CALCULATE_FRICTIONAL_TORQUE = LB_DONT_CALCULATE
IDSCO_LUBRICATION_AND_CONTAMINATION = LB_CONSIDER
[IDSCO_LUBRICANT]
IDSCO_VISCOSITY_CALCULATION_FLAG = LB_CALCULATE_VISCOSITY_GLOBAL
IDSCO_ETA_C_CALCULATION_FLAG = LB_INPUT_ETAC
IDSCO_LUBRICANT_DEFINITION_FLAG = LB_DEFINITION_BY_INPUT
IDSCO_VISCOSITY_DEFINITION_FLAG = LB_DEFINITION_BY_CLASS
IDSCO_OILTEMP[0] = 70.0
IDSCO_NY[0] = 55.2
IDSCO_NY_40 = 240.0
IDSCO_NY_100 = 1.0
IDSCO_OIL_DENSITY[0] = 890.0
IDSCO_ADDITIVES = LB_NO_ADDITIVES
IDSCO_KAPPA_CALCULATION_FLAG = LB_ACCORDING_ISO_281
IDSCO_ETA_C[0] = 0.70
IDSCO_FILTRATION = LB_FILTERED_OIL
IDSCO_LUBRICANT_TYPE = LB_OIL_LUBRICATION
IDSCO_CLEANLINESS_CODE_RECIRCULATING_OIL = LB_ISO17_14_DP25
IDSCO_CLEANLINESS_CODE_OIL_BATH = LB_ISO17_14
IDSCO_CLEANLINESS_CODE_GREASE = LB_NORMAL_CLEANLINESS_GREASE
IDSCO_INITIAL_GREASING = LB_YES
IDSCO_DESIGNATION_OF_GREASE = LB_GA01
IDSCO_INFLUENCE_OF_AMBIENT = LB_AVERAGE_AMBIENT_INFLUENCE
IDSCO_CALCULATE_GREASE_SERVICE_LIFE = LB_NO
IDSCO_SPECIFICATION_OF_OIL_LEVEL = LB_DESCRIPTION
IDSCO_OIL_LEVEL_RELATIVE_TO_DW = 50.00
IDSCO_DESCRIPTION_OF_OIL_LEVEL = LB_OIL_MIST_LUBRICATION
[IDCO_LOCATION]
IDCO_LOCATION_IS_LOADCASE_DEPENDENT = IFALSE
IDCO_X = -498.300
IDCO_Y = 0.000
IDCO_Z = -229.800
IDCO_EPSILON_X = 0.000000000000000000
IDCO_EPSILON_Y = 0.000000000000000000
IDCO_EPSILON_Z = 0.000000000000000000
IDSS_PLANET_SHAFT_SYSTEM_WITH_RELATIVE_LOCATION = LB_NO
IDSS_REFERENCE_PLANET_SHAFT_SYSTEM = ""
IDSS_RELATIVE_ROTATION_REGARDING_THE_REFERENCE_PLANET_SHAFT_SYSTEM = 0.000000000000000000
[IDSS_OPERATINGDATA]
IDSS_MAXIMUM_SIGV = 0.0
IDSS_SHAFT_NUMBER_MAXIMUM_SIGV = "-"
IDSS_BEARING_NUMBER_MINIMUM_LN = "e1f0ec0b-9ea7-4009-a3ff-77bf9bad5ae8"
IDSS_BEARING_NAME_MINIMUM_LN = "SL182220"
IDSS_MINIMUM_LN = 1749392.4604
IDSS_BEARING_NUMBER_MINIMUM_LKM = ""
IDSS_BEARING_NAME_MINIMUM_LKM = " - "
IDSS_BEARING_NUMBER_MINIMUM_LH = "e1f0ec0b-9ea7-4009-a3ff-77bf9bad5ae8"
IDSS_BEARING_NAME_MINIMUM_LH = "SL182220"
IDSS_MINIMUM_LH = 19436916
IDSS_BEARING_NUMBER_MINIMUM_S0 = "e1f0ec0b-9ea7-4009-a3ff-77bf9bad5ae8"
IDCO_BEARING_MINIMUM_S0_W = "e1f0ec0b-9ea7-4009-a3ff-77bf9bad5ae8"
IDSS_BEARING_NAME_MINIMUM_S0 = "SL182220"
IDSS_MINIMUM_S0 = 120.982
IDSS_BEARING_INDEX_MINIMUM_S0 = 1
IDSS_BEARING_NUMBER_MINIMUM_GREASE_SERVICE_LIFE = ""
IDSS_NOTCH_CREATION_FLAG = INTERACTIVE_NOTCH_CREATION
IDSS_FLAG_FOR_GEAR_CALCULATION = LB_INCLUDED_IN_GEAR_CALCULATION
[IDSS_LOAD_CYCLE_INPUT]
IDSS_LOAD_CYCLE_INPUT_NUMBER_OF_DISCRETISATION_STEPS = 4
IDSS_LOAD_CYCLE_INPUT_TYPE_OF_DISCRETIZED_LOADS_SUPERPOSITION = LB_SUPERPOSE_DISCRETIZED_LOADS_COMMUTATED
[IDCO_VISUALIZATION]
IDCO_VISUALIZATION_STATUS = LB_SOLID_BODY
IDCO_VISUALIZE_LABEL = IFALSE
IDCO_VERTICAL_LABEL_POSITION = 30
IDCO_HORIZONTAL_LABEL_POSITION = 30
IDCO_DEPTH_LABEL_POSITION = 0
[IDSCO_VISUALIZATION]
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_ALGORITHM = LB_SCALE_FACTOR_FROM_MODEL_DIMENSIONS
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_LOADS_MM_PER_UNIT = 0.010
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_MOMENTS_MM_PER_UNIT = 0.010
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_DISTRIBUTED_LOADS_MM_PER_UNIT = 0.010
IDSCO_SCALE_FACTOR_DISTRIBUTED_MOMENTS_MM_PER_UNIT = 0.010
[IDSS_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_DATA]
IDSS_BASIS_MAX_FREQUENCY = 10471.975511966
IDSS_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_CONSIDER_STIFFENING_DUE_TO_AXIAL_LOAD = LB_YES
IDSS_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_FILTEROUT_0_FREQUENCIES = LB_YES
IDSS_NATURAL_FREQUENCIES_SHOULD_BE_CALCULATED = LB_YES
IDSS_STATUS_OF_NATURAL_FREQUENCIES_CALCULATION[0] = IFALSE
IDSS_CRITICAL_SPEEDS_SHOULD_BE_CALCULATED = LB_NO
IDSS_STATUS_OF_CRITICAL_SPEEDS_CALCULATION[0] = IFALSE
IDSS_TRANSIENT_RESPONSE_SHOULD_BE_CALCULATED = LB_NO
IDSS_STATUS_OF_TRANSIENT_RESPONSE_CALCULATION[0] = IFALSE
IDSS_UNBALANCE_RESPONSE_SHOULD_BE_CALCULATED = LB_NO
IDSS_UNBALANCE_RESPONSE_LOWER_ROTATING_SPEED = 0.000000000000000000
IDSS_UNBALANCE_RESPONSE_UPPER_ROTATING_SPEED = 100000.000000000
IDSS_UNBALANCE_RESPONSE_NUMBER_OF_CALCULATION_STEPS = 100
IDSS_STATUS_OF_UNBALANCE_RESPONSE_CALCULATION[0] = IFALSE
IDSS_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_CALL_DYNLIB = LB_YES
IDSS_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_SAVE_DYNLIB_MODEL_TO_INTERMEDIATE_FILE = LB_NO
IDSS_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_PATH_TO_DYNLIB_INTERMEDIATE_FILE = "DynLibModel.xml"
[IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION]
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_MODESHAPES_RELATIVE_SCALE_FACTOR[0] = 2.0
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_MODESHAPES_RELATIVE_SCALE_FACTOR_TORSION_LINE[0] = 0.3
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_RELATIVE_SCALE_FACTOR[0] = 5.0
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_SCALE_FACTOR_DISPLACEMENT[0] = 1000.0
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_SCALE_FACTOR_INCLINATION[0] = 1.0
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_SCALE_FACTOR_FORCE[0] = 1.0
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_SCALE_FACTOR_MOMENT[0] = 1.0
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_SCALE_FACTOR_SPEED[0] = 1.0
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_SCALE_FACTOR_ACCELERATION[0] = 1.0
IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_ANIMATION_TIME[0] = 2.0
[IDSCO_EXTERNAL_MASS_LOAD]
IDSCO_ROTATION_RADIUS = 0.000
IDSCO_EPS_X_ACCELERATION[0] = 0.000000000000000000
IDSCO_SPEED_OF_ROTATION[0] = 0.00000
[IDCO_IMPORT_LOAD_DATA]
IDCO_FILE_NAME = ""
IDCO_FIRST_DATA_LINE = 1

[/IDO_SHAFT_SYSTEM[0]/IDO_RADIAL_ROLLER_BEARING] [0]
```

Comment: your code is overcomplicated, why do you pass IDs to the searchIDs and searchProp if you are not using it?

Comment: @Ralf the code for searchIDs() is there.

Comment: @woockashek Because later on I will be using all of those

Comment: can you increment `lineNum` at the end of the loop `for line in mdl:`

Comment: @damagedCoda I changed it but it did'nt help

Comment: can you post a snapshot of the text file with the second ID or if you have git for the entire code do post that.

Comment: @damagedCoda I added the relevant text to the question.

Comment: reset the `mdl` to start from the beginning of the file using `mdl.seek(0)` inside the `searchIDs` function. Since you have opened `mdl` and arent reading it again.

Comment: @damagedCoda this results in the code running many times over what it should. I think I may have a new problem with the code, thanks though as this does get it to run the second string.

Answer (score 1):

Once you read something through the file it's important to reset your pointer to point to the start of the file.

```
def searchIDs(mdl, IDs, Properties, i):
    lineNum = 0
    print('blah')
    mdl.seek(0)
    for line in mdl:
        #print(line)
        if i in line:
            ID = i
            print("Line number is: ")
            print(lineNum)
            print("ID is: " + ID)
            print("Line is: " + line)
            #searchProp(mdl, jsonCopy, IDs, Properties, lineNum, ID)
        lineNum += 1
```

ignore the debugging print statements but i guess it should solve your problem!

Comment: I tried this earlier but it results in a print out significantly larger than it should be, its like it runs over the loop many, many extra times

Answer (score 0):

In `searchIDs` function add `mdl.seek(0)` and an if_statement for stop searching.

```
def searchIDs(mdl, IDs, Properties, i):

lineNum = 0
mdl.seek(0)
for line in mdl:

    lineNum += 1
    if i in line:
        ID = i
        print("Line number is: ")
        print(lineNum)
        print("ID is: " + ID)
        print("Line is: " + line)
        searchProp(mdl, IDs, Properties, lineNum, ID)
    if lineNum == sum(1 for line in open('test.txt')):
        break
```

Instead of `'test.txt'` set the file name that search it.